# express mongoDB aggregation sum

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose, aggregation

I have many records in my mongodb collection and I need to recount some information.

records format:

```
{
    "_id" : someId,
    "targetFrom" : ObjectId("603e0355e805140334e79438"),<-- this is ID for search
    "targetTo" : null,
    "operationPaid" : true,
    "type" : "coming", <--- type
    "moneyAccount" : someId,
    "agent" : null,
    "sum" : 5000, <--- sum
}
{
    "_id" : someId,
    "targetFrom" : null,
    "targetTo" : null,
    "operationPaid" : true,
    "type" : "out", <--- type
    "moneyAccount" : someId,
    "agent" : ObjectId("603e0355e805140334e79438"),<-- this is ID for search
    "sum" : 3000, <--- sum
}
```

so, I need to group by records **TYPE** and get **SUM** for id ObjectId("603e0355e805140334e79438"), but id for search can be field **targetFrom** or **targetTo** or **agent**

for this example I need to get result **2000**

sum **5000** is **coming** and sum **3000** is **out** with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query

- match the Id in one of the 3 possible fields
- group by null (all collection 1 group), if `type="out"` i subtract the sum field else i add to sum field

[Test code here](https://cmql.org/play/?q=70629537-m)

```js
aggregate(
[{"$match":
  {"$expr":
   {"$or":
    [{"$eq":["$targetFrom", ObjectId("603e0355e805140334e79438")]},
     {"$eq":["$targetTo", ObjectId("603e0355e805140334e79438")]},
     {"$eq":["$agent", ObjectId("603e0355e805140334e79438")]}]}}},
 {"$group":
  {"_id":null,
   "sum":
   {"$sum":
    {"$cond":
     [{"$eq":["$type", "out"]}, {"$subtract":[0, "$sum"]}, "$sum"]}}}}])
```

Comment: one more question. what I need to add to get only records where field operationPaid is true? thank you

Comment: i think you mean [this](https://cmql.org/play/?q=1641643710344)

Comment: exactly. thank you again!
χρόνια πολλά με υγεία και αγάπη :P